# Place DIV over other DIV and Image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML ([Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EeI18Q0IdYo5W9KDKuMC?p=preview)):

```
<div class="first">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>

<div class="second">
  Lorem Ipsum ...
</div>
```

I need to place part of the second DIV over the first DIV so I used:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 100;
}

.first img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.second {
  background-color: red;
  margin: -80px 0 auto;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

What is strange is the text in second DIV appears over the image but not the second DIV. Red should be over the image as the text is ...

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Add position:relative to .second. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/ https://jsfiddle.net/10L7fad9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `<div>` elements are `position: static` which ignores positional CSS including `z-index`. Adding `position: relative` to the `.second` element allows `z-index` to work properly.

I also changed the negative margin to `top: -80px`, which is cleaner.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 100;
}

.first img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.second {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 200;

  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="first">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>


</body>
```

Comment: I missed that ... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`position: relative;` in the second div

Comment: plus one here, not because of your name. i think @MiguelMoura is a shared account bought from RMT player of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Try relatively positioning the second div:

```
.second {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
.second {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 200;
 }
```